# Azure pipeline Deploy to Amazon Lambda seldom fails on build

Tags: .net-core, deployment, aws-lambda, azure-devops, pipeline

This doesn't happen very often, but I'd like to know why Azure pipeline sometimes fail.. Here is the error:

[image: failed lambda deploy screenshot]
[image: successful lambda deploy screenshot]

Here is the **raw logs** from Azure:

> The task also requires permissions to upload your Lambda function or
>   serverless application content to the specified Amazon S3 bucket.
>   Depending on the size of the application bundle, either putObject or
>   the S3 multi-part upload APIs may be used.
>   ============================================================================== Configuring credentials for task ...configuring AWS credentials from
>   service endpoint '0fccf46b-rAnDom-GuId-f8a4f1351ac1' ...endpoint
>   defines standard access/secret key credentials Processing Lambda
>   project at D:\a\1\s\FooService\FooProject.Services.Foo Reading
>   existing aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json Clearing out profile foo so
>   task credentials will be used. Configuring region for task
>   ...configured to use region ap-southeast-1, defined in task.
>   [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" tool install -g
>   Amazon.Lambda.Tools Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you
>   will need to reopen the Command Prompt window before running the tool
>   you installed. You can invoke the tool using the following command:
>   dotnet-lambda Tool 'amazon.lambda.tools' (version '4.0.0') was
>   successfully installed.
>
> [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" restore   Restore
>   completed in 63.09 ms for
>   D:\a\1\s\Infrastructure\FooProject.Infrastructure\FooProject.Infrastructure.csproj.
>   Restore completed in 63.07 ms for
>   D:\a\1\s\FooService\FooProject.Services.Foo\FooProject.Services.Foo.csproj.
>
> Beginning Serverless Deployment Performing package-only build of
>   serverless application, output template will be placed in
>   D:\a\1\a\serverless.template [command]"C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" lambda package-ci -ot
>   D:\a\1\a\serverless.template --region ap-southeast-1 --s3-bucket
>   foo-dev-bucket --disable-interactive true Could not execute
>   because the specified command or file was not found. Possible reasons
>   for this include:   * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.   *
>   You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-lambda does
>   not exist.   * You intended to run a global tool, but a
>   dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the
>   PATH.
>
> [error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
>   [section]Finishing: Deploy .NET Core to Lambda:  fooProject-api-foo

Here is the setup:

[image: Azure deploy lambda setup]

Comment: Which agent is used to run? hosted agent or self-hosted agent?